# Notice undefined user variable and fatal error call to a member function

Tags: function, variables, authentication, notice

I am new to PHP and I am trying to make a login system. Now when I click on login I get these errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_logged_in() on null in C:\xampp3\htdocs\wb_html\login.php on line 6.

Any ideas on how to define the user variable and on how to make a function for `is_logged_in`? I know I am being stupid but any help will be appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
//include config
require_once('includes/config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if($user->is_logged_in()){
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo "<a href=register.php>Register</a>  <a href=login.php>Login</a>";
}

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }
}//end if submit

//define page title
$title = 'Login';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
```